# Uniqueness of sequence limit

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> The original poster [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/882250/proving-that-a-convergent-sequence-has-a-unique-limit) (I think) assumes that $L\ne M$, so essentially, $\lim _{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n\in\{L,M\}$. But OP assumes in his proof at one point that $\lim _{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=L$. Is that okay?

I have this question because in answer by Andres Nicolas, it is said that if we have proved relevant result about the limit of a sum, or difference, the proof by OP is fine.

Comment: No his proof is not correct,because he assumed a priori that $L \neq M$

Answer (score 1):

No, it is false. In analogy the proof runs as follows: If $a=b$ and $a=c$, then $b-c = a-a = 0$, so $b = c$. This does not utilize the notion of limit.