# Proof verification: a convergent complex sequence has a unique limit.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, solution-verification

So I'm doing the exercises in Stein-Shakarchi, Vol. I and the question is as follows:

> A sequence of complex numbers $\{w_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is said to converge if there exists a $w\in\Bbb{C}$ such that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}|w_n-w|=0.$$
> Show that a convergent sequence of complex numbers has a unique limit.

My proof is as follows:

Let the limit of the convergent sequence $\{w_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be non-unique and let it converge to both $w$ and $w'$. Then we need to show that $w'=w$. We have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}|w_n-w|=0$$ and $$\lim_{n\to\infty}|w_n-w'|=0.$$ Since $|z|$ is real for all $z\in\Bbb{C}$, we can use the algebraic limit theorem to write $$\lim_{n\to\infty}|w_n-w|+\lim_{n\to\infty}|w_n-w'|=\lim_{n\to\infty}|w_n-w|+|w_n-w'|=0.$$ Now use the triangle inequality to get $$0=\lim_{n\to\infty}|w_n-w|+|w_n-w'|\geq\lim_{n\to\infty}|w_n-w+w_n-w'|=\lim_{n\to\infty}|2w_n-w-w'|$$ and thus we get $\lim_{n\to\infty}|w_n-\frac{w+w'}{2}|\leq 0$. But absolute value is non-negative, so $\lim_{n\to\infty}|w_n-\frac{w+w'}{2}|=0$ and $\frac{w+w'}{2}$ is also a limit of the sequence $\{w_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$. We thus have $w$(or $w'$) = $\frac{w+w'}{2}$ and so $w=w'$.

Is this proof correct? Since I'm assuming the sequence converges to $w$ and $w'$, I figure the last statement in the proof is valid? Am I wrong in my reasoning?

Comment: I don’t know if you can assume that $\frac{w’+w}{2}=w$ as the sequence can have 3 or more limits possibly. I think you need to write $|w_n-w|=|w-w_n|$ first before triangle inequality so as to cancel out the $w_n$s. (Also I don’t know if I should put this as an answer or comment so I’m leaving it here)

Answer (score 1):

I've found a way to solve this more directly, without having to resort to the uniqueness of limits for $\operatorname{Re}(w_n)$ and $\operatorname{Im}(w_n)$.

Let the sequence converge to two different limits, $w$ and $w'$. Then, we have from the given definition of convergence
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}|w_n-w|=\lim_{n\to\infty}|w_n-w'|=0.$$
Using the algebraic limit theorem $\lim f \pm g = \lim f \pm \lim g$ and the inequality $|a-b|\geq |a|-|b|$ for complex $a$ and $b$, we have
$$0=\lim_{n\to\infty}|w_n-w|-\lim_{n\to\infty}|w_n-w'|=\lim_{n\to\infty}|w_n-w|-|w_n-w'|\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}|w_n-w-w_n+w'|$$
from which we get $|w'-w|\geq 0$.
Also we have using the triangle inequality,
$$0=\lim_{n\to\infty}|w_n-w|+\lim_{n\to\infty}|w_n-w'|=\lim_{n\to\infty}|w_n-w|+\lim_{n\to\infty}|w'-w_n|\geq\lim_{n\to\infty}|w_n-w+w'-w_n|$$
from which we get $|w'-w|\leq 0.$ Therefore, we must have $|w'-w|=0$ and hence $w'=w$.

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote proves that if $w$ and $w'$ are limits of the sequence $(w_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$, then $\frac{w+w'}2$ is also the limit of that sequence. But you cannot deduce from this that $w=\frac{w+w'}2$ or $w'=\frac{w+w'}2$, unless you know that a convergente sequence cannot have more than one limit. And that is what you want to prove.

Comment: I see, I guess I'll have to do it by assuming the real and imaginary parts converge and use the uniqueness of limits for real sequences.

Comment: You don't need to do that. See the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/882250/proving-that-a-convergent-sequence-has-a-unique-limit).